# npm audit fails cannot find package-lock

Tags: npm, package.json, package-lock.json, npm-audit

I have this configuration:

```
$ node -v
v16.13.0

$ npm -v
8.1.2

$ npm config get shrinkwrap
true

$ npm config get package-lock
true
```

FWIW I'm on macOS 10.15.17 and Node.js is installed via MacPorts.

When I run `npm install` or `npm install --package-lock-only` there is no `package-lock.json` which is created.  There is, however, this:

```
$ ls -l node_modules/.package-lock.json 
-rw-r--r--  1 david  admin  301536 Dec 14 18:48 node_modules/.package-lock.json
```

That date is within the last 10 minutes.  I have removed `node_modules` and rerun the install.  And, I have run `npm cache clean --force`.

When I run `npm install` the output talks about some moderate severity vulnerabilities.  I obviously want to learn more, but get this:

```
$ npm audit
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/david/.npm/_logs/2021-12-15T02_48_57_735Z-debug.log
```

Running `npm audit fix` or `npm audit fix --force` doesn't change anything.

The first message - requires a lockfile - why isn't `node_modules/.package-lock.json` good enough?

The debug log doesn't contain any useful information.

I have read several postings on stackoverflow and elsewhere and have collected the recommended information.  Supposedly with this config, the file should be created, and then `npm audit` would be happy.  But, it's not.